# Selenium BIDI - Read the specific requests sent from the web app

Tags: selenium-webdriver, request, google-chrome-devtools

I need to capture the some of the specific requests sent out from a web application. We don't want to use CDP version specific API - Version specific CDP commands are available - org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools#addListener.

So we looked at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.NetworkInterceptor :

```java
webDriver = new Augmenter().augment(webDriver);
devTools = ((HasDevTools) webDriver).getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();
this.interceptor = new NetworkInterceptor(webDriver,
        Route.matching(req -> (req.getUri().contains(URL) && req.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST)))
                .to(() -> req -> {
                    System.out.println("Hello redd DDD");
                    System.out.println("URI : " + req.getUri());
                    System.out.println(req.getMethod());
                    return new HttpResponse();
                }));
```

However we don't want to stub out the responses , in fact we are looking for ways to stay away from tinkering the responses. We only need to get the requests and run validation against it .

What is happening now: As these methods needs stubbing out the responses , the web-apps state gets corrupted and it gets log out.

Is there any other way to "read a particular requests " sent out. your help much appreciated.

P.S: Is there a way to use the NetworkInterceptor without tinkering the response. Route, Handler and filter all three constructors needs sending back response.  I am testing for requests sent out for event logging in our web app and need only need to read the requests emanating.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium java You can access the network Requests sent out using `Network.requestWillBeSent`

Network.requestWillBeSent() is an event in the CDP that is triggered when a network request is about to be sent. This event provides information about the request that is going to be sent, including the request URL, headers, method, and request body.

Full Code

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("w3c", true);
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
    devTools.createSession();

    devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));

    devTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(), request -> {
        String url = request.getRequest().getUrl();
        System.out.println(url);
        Headers headers = request.getRequest().getHeaders();
        Stream.of(headers).forEach(head -> System.out.println(head.toString()));
        String method = request.getRequest().getMethod();
        System.out.println(method);
        request.getRequest().getPostData();
    });
    driver.get("https://www.sample.com/");
     //DO some actions
    devTools.close();
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: My aim is to be agnostic to the CDP version. This is not -->import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v112.network.Network;

Comment: Yes, those will change with every release. If you choose to use the raw DevTool protocol API, you’re tying yourself to a *specific* version of Chrome. This is the same reason that CDP-based automation libraries like Puppeteer tie their releases to specific versions of Chrome. Selenium provides version-agnostic APIs for common things that many people want to use CDP for, like network 
request/response interception and manipulation. If you find those APIs lacking, it would be instructive to know your use case, and how common it is.

Comment: [Source](https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/dF48mBon2x8/m/mRQFw2FkCAAJ)

Comment: As an alternative you can always use Browser mob
 [Browser mob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)

Comment: Browser mob don't have any recent development and it may have vulnerabilites  . thats why we don't want to go that way.

Answer (score 0):

Within the org.openqa.selenium.devtools.NetworkInterceptor class, you'll find a static field named **PROCEED_WITH_REQUEST**.

This field enables the seamless continuation of a request without any need for modification or manipulation of the response.

Please, take a look at the code snippet below:

```
    AtomicReference<String> uri = new AtomicReference<>();
    AtomicReference<String> method = new AtomicReference<>();


    try (NetworkInterceptor interceptor =
                 new NetworkInterceptor(
                         driver,
                         Route.matching(req -> req.getUri().endsWith("somePartialPath"))
                                 .to(() -> req -> {
                                     uri.set(req.getUri());
                                     method.set(req.getMethod().name());
                                     return NetworkInterceptor.PROCEED_WITH_REQUEST;
                                 }))) {

        driver.get("https://www.sample.com/");
       
        System.out.println(uri);
        System.out.println(method);
    }
```